# ¿Se puede descargar un archivo .docm desde un servidor JSP?

Tags: javascript, html5, jsp, descarga

Cuando descargo desde mi aplicación jsp, los archivos .docm y los abro, me aparece el mensaje: "Lo sentimos. No se puede abrir doc1.docm por que hay un problema con el contenido."
Si renombro ese archivo cambiándole la extensión a .docx se puede visualizar.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que se descargue de forma correcta en .docm?

PD:Estoy utilizando la librería docx4j.

Comment: Si estás descargando , significa que tu pregunta [¿Se pueden crear archivos docm con javasacript desde jsp?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162066/15855) está resuelta?

Comment: No, igual me he explicado mal. Me deja descargarlo con la extensión .docm, pero cuando intento abrir el archivo me da un error: Lo sentimos. No se puede abrir doc1.docm porque existe un problema con el contenido-